# Cloudera configuration - Multi NIC

Tags: networking, hadoop, cluster-computing, hdfs, cloudera

I'm trying to setup a multi-NIC cluster with Cloudera5. Each node has an ethernet interface (eth1 - 172.17.2.x) plus an infiniband interface (ib0 - 192.168.69.x).
The problem is, the cluster communicates the infiniband addresses to the "outside world" when using HDFS.
I found out that the right parameter to get such a configuration working is "dfs.datanode.dns.interface" and that it has to be set to "eth1".

However, this parameter is not present in the Cloudera Manager interface. As it automatically overwrites the hdfs-site.xml file, I can't go to write it in the file.

I tried to use the Cloudera manager "Safety Valves" (Configuration > Service-Wide > Advanced > HDFS Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hdfs-site.xml), and set it to

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.dns.interface</name>
    <value>eth1</value>
</property>
```

but the HDFS Canary fails.

Could anyone please

- Confirm that it's the right parameter
- give me some help on how to set
  it in the Cloudera Manager interface ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add further configuration properties that is not present in the CM interface filling these field in the HDFS configuration page: 
- HDFS Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hdfs-site.xml"
- Cluster-wide Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for core-site.xml
- HDFS Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hadoop-policy.xml

In yout case you have to insert this code:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.dns.interface</name>
    <value>eth1</value>
</property>
```

in the HDFS Service Advanced Configuration Snippet